# Using fgetc to pass only part of a text file to a buffer

Tags: c, string

I have the following text file:

```
13.69 (s, 1H), 11.09 (s, 1H).
```

So far I can quite happily use either fgets or fgetc to pass all text to a buffer as follows:

```
    char* data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); 

    int c; 
    int n = 0; 

    FILE* inptr = NULL;
    inptr = fopen("NMR", "r");

    if(NULL == fopen("NMR", "r"))
    {
        printf("Error: could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (c = fgetc(inptr); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(inptr))
    {

        data[n++] = c;

    }

    for (int i = 0, n = 100; i < n; i++)
    {

       printf ("%c", data[i]); 
    }

    printf("\n");
```

and then print the buffer to the screen afterwards. However, I am only looking to pass part of the textfile to the buffer, namely:

```
13.69 (s, 1H),
```

So this means I want fgetc to stop after ','. However, this means the that the text will stop at 13.69 (s,    and not 13.69 (s, 1H),
Is there a way around this? I have also experimented with fgets and then using strstr as follows:

```
   char needle[4] = ")";
   char* ret;

   ret = strstr(data, needle);

   printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
```

However, the output from this is:

```
), 11.09 (s, 1H)
```

thus giving me the rest of the string which I do not want. It's an interesting one and if anyone has any tips it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the closing parenthesis is the last character you want, you can use that as your stopping point in the `fgetc()` loop:

```
char data[100]; //No need to dynamically allocate if we know the size at compile time

int c;
int n = 0;

FILE* inptr = NULL;
inptr = fopen("NMR", "r");

if(inptr == NULL)   //We want to check the value of the file we just opened
{                   //and plan to use
    printf("Error: could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}

//We'll keep the original value guards (EOF and '\n') below and add two more
//to make sure we break from the loop
//We use n<98 below to make sure we can always create a null-terminated string,
//If we used 99, the 100th character might be a ')', then we have no room for a
//terminating null-char
for (c = fgetc(inptr); c != ')' && n < 98 && c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(inptr))
{
    data[n++] = c;
}

if(c != ')') //We hit EOF, \n, or ran out of space in data[]
{
    printf("Error: no matching sequence found\n");
    return 2;
}
data[n]=')';    //Could also write data[n]=c here, since we know it's a ')'
data[n+1]='\0'; //Add the terminating null character

printf("%s\n",data); //Since it's a properly formatted string, we can use %s
```

(Note that this example will handle null input characters differently from yours. If you expect null characters to be in the input stream (NMR file) then change the `printf("%s",...)` line back to the `for` loop you originally had.

Answer (score 1):

Well with only one example of the format you are trying to parse it's not totally possible to give an answer, however if your input is always like this I would simply have a counter and break after the second comma.

```
int comma = 0;
for (c = fgetc(inptr); c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != ',' && comma < 1; c = fgetc(inptr))
{
    if (data[n] = ',')
        comma++;
    data[n++] = c;
}
```

In case the characters inside the parenthesis can be more complex I would simply maintain a boolean state to know if I am actually inside or outside a parenthesis and break when I read a comma outside of it.

Comment: Cheers. Well ultimately in the final version the plan is not to break, but instead to increment and change to the next node of a linked list and pass the next segment of text to an array in there. Would that be feasible based on the logic so far?

Comment: With the second solution with the state inside parenthesis or not yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Simply read using `fgets` and store desired string in `char *` using `sscanf`-

```
char *new_data;
new_data=malloc(100);  // allocate memory
...
fgets(data,100,inptr);               // read from file but check its return
sscanf(data,"%[^)]",new_data);       // store string untill ')' in new_data from data
strcat(new_data,")");                // concatenating new_data and ")"
printf("%s",new_data);                    // print new_data
...
free(new_data);                     // remember to free memory
```

Also you should check return of `malloc` though not done in my example and also close the file opened .